Why is the object passed to the SimpleKeyValueRepository.delete(T obj) method ignored, and the HGETALL method is executed to retrieve the same object?
I am curious as to why Spring Data Redis does not provide support for custom deleteBy methods? For this reason, we have to use a workaround to perform these methods: a service method that calls the findBy method and passes the resulting object to the delete(T obj) method.
When examining the commands that Spring Data Redis executes on the database, I noticed that the HGETALL command is executed twice: once in the findBy method and once in the delete(T obj) method. It is interesting to understand why the delete(Obj) method retrieves the object that we already received in order to perform the delete operation?
The service method that I am running:
public void deleteByName(String name) {
    People people = peopleRepository.findByName(name);
    componentRepository.delete(people);
}

PeopleRepository:
public interface PeopleRepository extends KeyValueRepository<People, Long> {
    People findByName(String name);
}


Do you access it in the same transaction? Is the deleting transaction committed at the time of query?

@ValerijDobler
I'm sorry if I don't know something. As far as I know, in Spring Data Redis it is impossible to wrap methods from Spring Data Redis repositories in a transaction, for example, via annotation Transactional.
I added an example of a service method that I am running to the description of the issue.
Rather, the transaction is not an issue, because the RedisKeyValueAdapter's delete(Object id, String keyspace, Class type) method calls for an object to be retrieved through the HGETALL command, which is invoked by the SimpleKeyValueRepository's delete(T entity) method.
